# best way to join by multiple columns and avoid OR in SQL

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, hana

I need a recommendation.

I have two tables. Table 1 is the main table and table 2 is the table that I initially thought to join Table 1 through a left join, table 2 is much larger than table 1. What would be the best performing way to join Table 1 and Table 2 being the union condition that Column b is equal to column b or that column c is equal to column c and column d is equal to column d, that is, any of these conditions is met but no empty values are met. This without using OR in the left join due to the poor performance it would have and the execution time. I appreciate any help.

Note: table 1 and table 2 is the result of 40 lines query. Database do not support recursive query. The database is sap hana.

Table 1

| ID | column b | column c | column d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d | g | j |
| 2 | e | h | k |
| 3 | f | i |  |

Table 2

| ID_2 | column b | column c | column d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | d | g |  |
| 5 |  |  | k |
| 6 |  | i |  |

Desired Result

| ID | column b | column c | column d | ID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d | g | J | 4 |
| 2 | e | h | k | 5 |
| 3 | f | i |  | 6 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `left join`s:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(t2_b.id_2, t2_c.id_2, t2_d.id_2) as id_2
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2_b
     on t1.b = t2_b.b left join
     table2 t2_c
     on t1.c = t2_d.c and t2_b.b is null
     table2 t2_d
     on t1.d = t2_d.d and t2_c.c is null;
```

Note that for optimal performance, you want three indexes:

- `table2(b, id_2)`
- `table2(c, id_2)`
- `table2(d, id_2)`

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do this without having to write the query multiple times and avoiding the use of 'with' because the database does not support the use of recursive query. Table 2 and Table 1 come from a query that is already heavy.

Comment: @RevanKnight . . . Use a CTE to define the values.  The question is about *tables*.  You might want to ask another question that is a better description of your actual problem.

Comment: You do _not_ want multi-column indices on HANA